# Show list of values by selecting the particular date

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting a list of values. By clicking on a particular date on mat-date-picker I want to show the list of values based on a particular date field.
Based on createddate field I want to display the lists.

**list of values in console log**

```
[{"id":"12345","name":"test","email":"test@gmail.com","mobile":"1111111111","createddate":"2020-07-29 15:32:32","lastModifieddate":"2020-07-29 15:32:32"}]
```

Comment: Please provide issue reproducible code or the code you have written so far to try to solve the issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

just filter the list. As mat-date-picker return a Date Object and the dates of the elements of your list are string you need convert the DateObject to String or Convert the dates of your object, e.g.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (dateChange)="dateChange($event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<div *ngFor="let item of filteredList">
{{item.name}}{{item.email}}{{item.createdDate}}
</div>


import {formatDate} from '@angular/common'

list:any[] //your list
filteredList:any[]  //the list filtered

dateChange(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent)
{
  //use formatDate
  dateSearch=formatDate(event.value,"yyyy-MM-dd");
  this.listFiltered=this.list.filter(x=>x.createdDate.substr(0,10)==dateSearch)
}
```